# Error que no existe un metodo usando Angular Fire Messaging

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript, firebase-messaging

Hola buenas estoy realizando una app para realizar envios de notificaciones usando firebase y angular, y busque en internet como hacerlo pero me da un error en un método de que no existe cuando es una importación. 
El error es el siguiente: **Property 'messaging' does not exist on type 'AngularFireMessaging'.ts(2339)**
Mostraré el servicio encargado de enviar los mensajes:

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe( //El error lo da en este método
      (_messaging) => {
      _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
      _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
      )
  }
  requestPermission() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
      (token) => {
        console.log(token);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      }
    );
  }
  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe((payload) => {
      console.log('new message received. ', payload);
      this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    });
  }
}
```

No entiendo muy bien porque no funciona, los pasos que seguí para hacerlo se encuentra en esta pagina web.
https://dev.to/mayurkadampro/angular-8-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-97a

Comment: Creo que es una errata, donde pones `this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe` seguramente quieres decir `this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe`

Comment: puse con messages pero luego el metodo que hay dentro del subscribe que pone onMessage no funciona y el onTokenRefresh, lo que he hecho ha sido eliminar lo que hay en el constructor y funciona pero muchas gracias por la aportacion